# How to access controller in didInsertElement

Tags: ember.js

I have a bootstrap dropdown which I need to activate once it has been inserted in the DOM. The view/controller is not associated to a route: it is just a component of my navigation bar. I configure the element id in the controller:

```
App.DropdownController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    elId : 'my-element-id',
});
```

So that I can use it in the template:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle opener" {{bind-attr id="elId"}} data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="icon-off icon-2x"></i>
</a>
...
```

But in `didInsertElement` I have to hack my way to get the controller:

```
App.DropdownView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'navbar/dropdown',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var controller = App.__container__.lookup('controller:dropdown'); // TODO: how to properly get controller?
        var elId = controller.get('elId');
        $('#' + elId).dropdown();
    }
});
```

How do I properly access the controller in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the view's `controller` [property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_controller) to access the controller. Using this property, you can access it in the `didInsertElement` handler like this.

```
var controller = this.get('controller');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `this.get('controller')`, however, in general it's better not to access the controller directly. My preference is to either push them or create a dependency. To push set them in markup that way the view defines its dependencies and they're passed in, as opposed to pulled.

```
{{view elId=eldId}}
```

Another option is to create a derived property.

```
App.DropdownView = Ember.View.extend({
  elId: function () { return this.get('controller.elid') }.property('controller.elid');
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $('#' + this.get('elId')).dropdown();
  }
});
```

The option looks similar to pulling, but having the derived property, removes the knowledge of where the property is coming from, from the place it's needed.